# Difference between "inspiring" and "inspirational"

Tags: differences, adjectives

What is the difference between the words *inspiring* and *inspirational*? In which context should one choose one over the other?

Comment: Reminds me of the difference between "historic" and "historical".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One difference is that *inspiring* always means that someone is actually inspired by it, whereas *inspirational* can also be used in compounds where it means only that something is *intended* to inspire; an *inspirational speaker* (or "motivational speaker"), for example, is someone whose job is to give speeches that are intended to inspire, without regard for whether they succeed (so ["boring inspirational speaker"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boring%20inspirational%20speaker%22) is not a contradiction in terms), and similarly, an *inspirational poster* (or "motivational poster") is a poster that is (supposedly) intended to inspire positive qualities, [but I don't think it generally succeeds](https://www.google.com/search?q=inspirational-posters&tbm=isch). But this use is non-predicative; in "the speaker was inspirational" (predicate adjective) or "a very inspirational poster" (modified by *very*), that meaning is not available, so in these cases *inspirational* just means *inspiring*.

Comment: An excellent answer, with one reservation: An inspiring speech (or whatever) need not come from an inspired speaker (or other creator); it only needs to inspire its beholder (to some action, thought, or feeling). However, an inspired speaker, except in a theo-historical context, must inspire someone to merit the label.

Comment: @HStephenStraight: When I say that "*inspiring* always means that someone is inspired", I mean that something is only 'inspiring' if it actually inspires someone. That is -- if someone is inspired *by it*. (Sorry for the belated response; it wasn't until just now that I finally realized what part of my answer you had a reservation about.)

Answer (score 6):

"Inspirational" shows intent; "Inspiring" shows effect. So, "Inspirational" often carries an ironic comment on the pretensions of the subject. It is often hyperbole. "Inspiring" is a clean and simple word meaning to be filled with breath which suggests that there was something "breathtaking" about the subjects action. I chose "inspiring" in all uses, except the ironic.

Answer (score 3):

From usage I have seen (to the limited extent I did), the two words are quite different.

***inspiring*** is typically used to qualify something *post-facto*: 'The speech was inspiring.'

***inspirational*** is common in qualifying in functional terms: 'He is going to deliver an inspirational speech.' (intended to be or do/ supposed to  be or do, looking forward).

I do not think we can find an authentic reference on the above lines, though.

Answer (score 3):

Having noticed that the word "Inspiring" has recently taken a back seat to "Inspirational", I decided to look up and see for myself what the differences between the two words might be.
For instance, Kate Middleton referred to Diana as "Inspirational."
I thought to myself, "Surely she was inspiring rather than "inspirational".
So, I chalked that up to nerves.
However, I've since noticed that nothing is "inspiring" anymore.  It's always "inspirational".
Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Inspirational is more closely associated with the spirit in a religious context; an example is "inspirational hymn".  Inspiring can have the same meaning but is used more commonly in the sense of uplifting or creating an impetus to action; an example is "the coach gave an inspiring half-time speech".

Comment: I feel like this answer asserts that "inspirational" is primarily used in religious contexts. It certainly can be understood that way, but isn't intrinsic to the word.

Answer (score 0):

Inspirational (adj) is with the intend to inspire, e.g. an inspirational speech.

Inspiring (adj, v) is delivering the impact, e.g. the speech is inspiring, or an inspiring coach.

Answer (score -2):

Verbs ending in -ing can be used as gerunds (nouns) or present participles (verbs or adjectives). "Inspiring" ends in ~ing. It is mostly used as a present participle and hence its usage as an adjective is correct.

"[I]nspirational" is always an adjective.

Comment: You've misunderstood *gerund* and *vowel*.